# Hard to update an Entity created by another LINQ to SQL context

Tags: linq-to-sql

Why this keep bugging me all day.

I have an entity with several references where i get from a context which I then Dispose.
Do some Changes and try to SubmitChanges(). While calling SubmitChanges() without .Attach() seems to simply do nothing. When using .Attach() I get the Exception :

An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L2S is very picky about updating an entity that came from a different DB context. In fact, you cannot do it unless you 'detach' it first from the context it came from. There are a couple different ways of detaching an entity. One of them is shown below. This code would be in your entity class.

```
public virtual void Detach()
{
    PropertyChanging = null;
    PropertyChanged = null;
}
```

In addition to this, you can also serialize your entity using WCF based serialization. Something like this:

```
    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(GetType());
        using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return serializer.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked implementing the ICloneable and using .Attach(newEntity, oldEntity). Thanx. I had to use /serialization option in sqlmetal too.